# https:// url for port 8443 lands on index in /var/www NOT its correct sub Dir

Tags: port-forwarding, https

After a long time I have finally got port 8443 to work albeit at the end of the URL(:8443).

However it lands on an html index page in the `/var/www/` directory not in on the index in the correct sub directory for that domain.

Obviously I need to tell it to go to that sub directory in a file, but not sure which one.

I have looked at some in a search, but not sure what applies to me.

Any guidance please?

Comment: first of all, what http server are you using, perhaps it's those search results that apply to you

Comment: Using apache2 with ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Do you have a virtual host config file for the site in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`? If so, what is the directory on the line for `DocumentRoot`? If you don't have this, then it's going to use the config file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` where `/var/www` is the default directory for access. It's also likely that you've set 8443 as the port in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.

Comment: Yes i did set 8443 in ports but in doc root I do have the sub dir dom directory for the domain not just the www dir. I will check apache2.conf though. Many thanks.

Comment: What was the url that you used?